# Insert label for x-y-axis on jquery chart

Tags: php, jquery, charts, label, axis

I have a chart build with jquery. I have correctly insert my data and the chart show it correctly. The code used is:

```
var plot = jQuery.plot(jQuery("#chartplace"), [{ 
    data: fatturato, 
    label: "Fatturato", 
    color: "#069"
}, { 
    data: spese,     
    label: "Spese", 
    color: "#FF6600"
}], {
    series: {
        lines: { 
            show: true, 
            fill: true, 
            fillColor: { 
                colors: [{ 
                    opacity: 0.05 
                }, { 
                    opacity: 0.15 
                }]
            } 
        },
        points: { 
            show: true 
        }
    },
    legend: { 
        position: 'nw'
    },
    grid: { 
        hoverable: true, 
        clickable: true, 
        borderColor: '#ccc', 
        borderWidth: 1, 
        labelMargin: 10 
    },
});
```

How can I insert a `label` for the `x` and `y` axis?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you perhaps show a demo as a jsFiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jqPlot (not currently tagged jqPlot) you need to add the following options to the chart configuration object you are supplying

```
axes:{
    xaxis:{
      label:'Some X Axis label'
    },
    yaxis:{
      label:'Some Y Axis label'
    }
  }
```

Documentation can be found at this [link](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/axisLabelTests.php).

Your final configuration should look like

```
var plot = jQuery.plot(jQuery("#chartplace"), [{ 
    data: fatturato, 
    label: "Fatturato", 
    color: "#069"
}, { 
    data: spese,     
    label: "Spese", 
    color: "#FF6600"
}], {
    series: {
        lines: { 
            show: true, 
            fill: true, 
            fillColor: { 
                colors: [{ 
                    opacity: 0.05 
                }, { 
                    opacity: 0.15 
                }]
            } 
        },
        points: { 
            show: true 
        }
    },
    axes:{
        xaxis:{
          label:'Some X Axis label'
        },
        yaxis:{
          label:'Some Y Axis label'
        }
      }
    legend: { 
        position: 'nw'
    },
    grid: { 
        hoverable: true, 
        clickable: true, 
        borderColor: '#ccc', 
        borderWidth: 1, 
        labelMargin: 10 
    },
});
```